# Verificar que la primera letra es una vocal

Tags: java, regex

Estoy intentando validar con una expresión regular que la primera letra es un vocal del siguiente modo, pero no lo consigo.

```
        String pattern = "[aeiouAEIOU]{1}[A-Za-z]";
    String buscar = "alphabet";
    if (buscar.matches(pattern))
        System.out.println("T");
    else
        System.out.println("F");
```

También he probado a cambiar el string pattern a

```
String pattern = "\\A[aeiouAEIOU]*";
```

alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String pattern = "^[aeiouAEIOU]{1}[A-Za-z]*";
```

Comment: Hola Abel, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Deberías editarla para darle formato al código y explicar qué es lo que hace. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Gracias Abel, es la única respuesta que ha pasado todas las pruebas funcionales.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar algo como esto:

```
/^[aeiou]{1}.*/i
```

Aquí una explicación de lo que hace:

- `^`: indica el principio de la cadena. De ese modo te aseguras de que la expresión regular se va a buscar al principio sólo y no entre medias (si no lo pones, cadenas como "casa" se considerarán válidas porque tienen una vocal entre medias).
- `[aeiou]{1}`: especifica uno solo de los caracteres contenidos entre los corchetes. Es decir, una de las vocales: `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`.
- `.*`: básicamente significa "cualquier cosa" (caracteres, símbolos, números...) Si quieres que sean sólo letras, puedes usar lo que tenías en una de tus pruebas: `[a-zA-Z]*`.
- `i`: indica que la cadena va a ser no sensible al case, es decir que admitirá mayúsculas y minúsculas igualmente.

Puedes ver esta expresión regular funcionando en [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KMnGSd/1).

---

En el caso de Java, para indicar que no sea sensible al case, en lugar de poner el `i` al final, debes poner `(?i)` al principio, con lo que la expresión regular ya funcionará:

```
(?i)^[aeiou]{1}.*
```

Comment: He probado a sustituir el string con tu código y el if sigue entrando en false... por lo que lamentablemente, sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: @RobertoGimenez es por la notación que he usado, por cómo lo haces, en lugar de usar los `/` y el `i` al final, puedes indicar que es independiente del case usando `(?i)` al principio. Por lo que la expresión regular quedaría así `(?i)^[aeiou]{1}.*`

Answer (score 0):

Ya estaba desesperado... pero creo haberlo encontrado...

String pattern = "[a-uA-U]{1}[A-Za-z]*";

Comment: Esta expresión regular no va a funcionar por al menos dos motivos: 1) No se hace ninguna indicación de dónde tiene que estar la cadena que se ajuste al patrón. Así la cadena "zulu" se considerará válida porque contiene una vocal en ella (la parte "ulu" hará que sea válida). 2) `[a-uA-U]` incluye mucho más que sólo las 5 vocales, son todos los caracteres comprendidos entre "a" y "u", lo cual incluye "b", "c", "d", etc. Por eso cadenas como "ccc" se considerarán válidas incluso cuando no empiezan o contienen ninguna vocal.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro, tienes razón... he estado probando como comentas, y mi código no funciona tal y como indicas.